# How to apply a geometry node to multiple objects?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I have many objects in my scene (hundreds) and want to apply a Geometry Node that I have made. I have named it "to_curve".

[image]

I am looking to attach and apply this modifier to every object in my scene. That is

```
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
# apply modifier "to_curve" on `o`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To copy GN modifiers,** select all objects, and set active object with GN modifier (by selecting with <kbd>Shift</kbd> if it is not active). Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> → *Copy modifiers*

**To apply modifiers,** (with objects selected) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → *Visual geometry to mesh*

**If you want to apply a specific modifier** that's already placed on some of the objects, here is the Python code:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

def apply_modifier(obj, mod):
    with context.temp_override(object=obj):
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    for mod in obj.modifiers:
        if mod.type == "NODES":
            if mod.node_group.name == "to_curve":
                apply_modifier(obj, mod)
```